# Identify groups and grouped rows in Excel file

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

I need to identify different groups in Excel files and rows inside these groups (to be more accurate I need to get the value of the first cell of the main row under which over rows are grouped).

Below is an example of the files structure (I've minimized the groups but when I receive these files they are expanded):

[image: Excel file structure]

I know how to create new groups using `openpyxl` or `xlwt`, I'm familiar with both `openpyxl` and `xlrd` but I'm enable to find anything in the API to solve this requirement.

So, is it possible using Python and if so, which part of `openpyxl` or `xlrd` API should I use ?

Comment: By my observations, the most powerful tool to tame Excel is `win32com.client` module. But it works on Windows only.

Comment: I'd rather have a Linux-compatible solution but I'll give win32com a look, I did not thought of it.

Comment: You should be able to do this with openpyxl. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I read the documentation of `openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions` module and played with Cell and Row classes but I did not find anything relevant to my issue. I know SO is not a code writing service and I should provide some code example, but I've currently no idea where to start. One idea I have is to minimize groups as in my screenshot and look for hidden rows but that doesnt seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the worksheet's `row_dimensions`. This returns an object accessible like a `dict` where the keys are the row numbers of the sheet. `outline_level` will have a non-zero value for each depth of grouping, or `0` if the row is not part of a group.

So, if you had a sheet where rows 2 and 3 were a group, and rows 5 and 6 were another group, iterating through `row_dimensions` would look like this:

```
>>> for row in range(ws.min_row, ws.max_row + 1):
...     print(f"row {row} is in group {ws.row_dimensions[row].outline_level}")
...
row 1 is in group 0
row 2 is in group 1
row 3 is in group 1
row 4 is in group 0
row 5 is in group 1
row 6 is in group 1
```

I should point out that there's some weirdness with accessing the information. My original solution was this:

```
>>> for row_num, row_data in ws.row_dimensions.items():
...     print(f"row {row_num} is group {row_data.outline_level}")
...
row 2 is group 1
row 3 is group 1
row 4 is group 0
row 5 is group 1
row 6 is group 1
```

Notice that row 1 is missing. It wasn't part of `row_dimensions` until I manually accessed it as `row_dimensions[1]` and then it appeared. I don't know how to explain that, but the first approach is probably better as it specifically iterates from the first to last row.

The same process applies to column groups through `column_dimensions` except that it must be keyed using column letter(s), e.g. `ws.column_dimensions["A"].current_level`.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no more "straightforward" solution for this, but that's exactly what I needed, thanks !